# Karma testing error with sample angular-seed project

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, npm, karma-runner

For trying Karma testing working with Angular, I get the angular-seed project (https://github.com/angular/angular-seed.git) from github. When running "bower install", it didn't work somehow so I simply got angular files manually into the intended directory(tell from app.js).

But after configuration(npm install and stuff), when running the "npm " command, the problem(angular is not defined) kept emerging. With the "npm test" command though, another problem (module is not defined) occurred still.
Anybody got idea how is it happening? Many thanks.

1.error when "npm start"

```
Chrome 35.0.1916 (Linux) controllers encountered a declaration exception FAILED
ReferenceError: module is not defined
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/administrator/文档/angular-seed/test/unit/controllersSpec.js:6:14)
    at /home/administrator/文档/angular-seed/test/unit/controllersSpec.js:5:1
```

(And 3 other similars)

2.error when "karma start"

```
Chrome 35.0.1916 (Linux) ERROR
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
at /home/administrator/文档/angular-seed/app/js/app.js:5

Chrome 35.0.1916 (Linux) ERROR
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
at /home/administrator/文档/angular-seed/app/js/controllers.js:5


Chrome 35.0.1916 (Linux) ERROR
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
at /home/administrator/文档/angular-seed/app/js/directives.js:6
```

And the important karma configuration is as below:

```
files: [
  'app/test/*/*.js',
  'app/js/*.js'
],
```

Answer (score 0):

dI'have already faced similar problem when Karma failed with `Uncaught ReferenceError: 'something' is not defined`. It differ every time, once it was jquery other times angular. I find out it has nothing to do with Karma configuration but with chrome browser. Tests only worked in FireFox but not in Chrome or PhantomJS. My colleague told me certain Karma version has this problems.

So try different browsers

Answer (score 0):

solution for 2 .error when `karma start`.

- edit `karma.config.js` and inside files:
  add path of angular.js file first and then add/list other `.js` files
- it will remove dependancy of angular. It will add `angular.js` first hence all the other libraries which are using `angular.js` will get reference of it.